# Scanning Barcodes into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, barcode-scanner, barcode

I am trying to scan barcodes into an Excel 2010 spreadsheet.  Each time I try to scan the barcode it tries to name the cell.  If I engage the cursor in cell it scans in the data, but I have to do this for each cell. How do I get it to bypass the "name game" and just input the data and go to the next cell?

Answer (score 1):

Select the whole column by clicking on the top of the column, then 'Format Cells', on the 'Number' tab select 'Text' then Hit OK.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this post will help  you which talks about issues on automatic [barcode reading](http://www.barcodelib.com/csharp/barcode_excel_csharp.html) function in Excel.

http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/49497/255510.aspx

Comment: Assuming the link is not spam (on my phone, can't really check), you should try to post information from that post, so that we have a copy here. It helps to also prevent link rot